# Вывод элементов массива в div с помощью jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Есть массив. Как его вывести в div с помощью jQuery?

```
let arr = ["Ann", 20, "Alex, 40"];
let string_1 = " ";
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i] !== undefined)
        string_1 += i + "-" + arr[i];
}
```

Comment: А что в этом массиве находится? Первый элемент строка, второй число, а третий строка, в которой строка и число.

Comment: в массиве строка , число и еще строка

Comment: Вы хотите именно через jQuery? По-моему это слишком тривиальная задача, с которой можно справиться с pure JS

Comment: да именно через jQuery, д/з задали, я начинающий

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если просто вывод с помощью jQuery, то тут используем [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) + [appendTo](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

```js
let arr = ["Ann", 20, "Alex, 40"];
$.each(arr, function( index, value ) {
  $('<p>' + value + '</p>').appendTo('.container');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
</div>
```

Тег `p` можно заменить на что вам угодно.

Comment: спасибо большое!